# Php form validation is not working

Tags: php

I've a html registration form where I set validation with php. It's doesn't work. If I put this function in my signup.php form then it's not working. But when i remove this function **inputvalid()** then it's working.

**Function.php page**

```
function inputvalid($para){
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para)));
return;
}
```

**Signup.php page**

```
$fname = inputvalid($_POST['fname']);
$lname = inputvalid($_POST['lname']);
```

If it's

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
```

then it's working. Why this happened?

Comment: You are not returning anything from your function ...

Comment: These are basic things you will learn in UG/PG. `If nothing return, you receive nothing`

Comment: I don't understand why people are crazy answer for these kind of questions. We are here to solve your issues not your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `return` keyword to return some value from your function

```
function inputvalid($para){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para)));
}
```

Comment: Well, @Vicekmi3, I updated my function. Please check it. If i set it like that it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

**You are not returning anything** from your function, use like this,

```
function inputvalid($para){
  return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para)));
}
```